# Dynamics CRM - Change Lookup (Autocomplete) View of Customer Entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2015

i'm new on microsoft dynamics crm. I need to customize a view of customer search field (what i understand as a autocomplete), in order to add some fields and allow users to search through these fields.

I found some links on internet and i found some authors that says that is necessary to change the views of the entities, however, i couldn't find any that could represent these specific view.

I'm attaching an image of the view that i want to customize.I want to know if it is possible to change it through the crm. If yes, where and what i should customize.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [Lookup View](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-customer-center/how-inline-lookup-works.aspx). Each entity has a quick find view which can be customized to an extent by adding a filter criteria etc. To have more granular level control over filter criteria you can use [Pre Search Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334481.aspx#BKMK_LookupPreSearch)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is what i was looking for.